Post json to url with tuya bluetooth gateway
I have a thermometer connected (via zigbee) to a gateway, this one is simple Tuya widget bought on aliexpress. Using the smart life app I can have the thermometer info anywhere, over internet.
But now I would like to post this data to windy.com, which is fairly simple, as this Python example below

import requests

base_url = "https://stations.windy.com/pws/update/"
API = ## a 123-chars string ##

data = {"observations":[{"station":0, "dateutc":"2024-12-16T10:21:34", "temp":27.8, "rh":51.9}]}

response = requests.post(base_url + API, json=data, verify=False, timeout=10)


I would like to use my gateway device to do a JSON post like that with the data from the thermometer every 5 minutes. I don't want to use any other device (Android phone, or a PC) for that task
I have no clue where to start from. Should I install another OS in the gateway? There is a Tuya API that could do it? ...

Your question isn't really answerable in its current state. As far as I can tell, you are asking how to add functionality to your Zigbee gateway, but you've told us absolutely nothing about it (not even the brand name!). There's no way to know if its current OS will let you install your own software or if the OS can be changed.

Sorry, since I'm new on this, I didn't imagine those infos were crucial. Did you click on the aliexpress link? I found there that the gateway is manufactured by szkoston, and nothing else. In the app I also can't find any other useful information. I started the question hoping that it could exist a simple answer, only based on the fact that the gateway uses Tuya platform and Zigbee communication.
